# Security Analysis On PCAP

Tags: security, sql-injection

I am totally new to SQL injections and I have a standard PCAP analysis, which has attacks like these below:

[image: SQL Injection Trace]

So I analysed the PCAP file using a python script and I am certain there is an SQL injection attack in place. MY query is, how does this attack works in the following case, viz,

```
id=10 or 1=1 union select null, concat(first_name,0x3a,pass) from users
```

or, for example frame 75, where some concatenation is done?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend a read of this article: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html . It discusses how attacks are used in the wild and talks you through some basic concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id=10` is probably generated by your page/app legitimately.

The rest pulls all records from the table (`or 1=1` is always true). `union` joins multiple result sets together, so tacks on additional results from another (`users`) table.

In this case, the concatenation is pulling the `first_name` field and the `password` field, separated by a colon (`0x3a` is an [ASCII colon](http://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/58))

However the page would normally show results, running it with the above query would tack on additional rows with name and password details, allowing an attacker to dump your sensitive information.

P.S. I hope the password field contains a salted hash, and not a password in plain text? If not, you'll need to start telling users their passwords have been leaked. Since many users reuse passwords everywhere, you've likely compromised other accounts too.

Edit: Re Frame 75:

This is a similar attack to the one highlighted above, except that instead of attempting to dump data from tables you've created, it's attempting to dump SQL's schema information (the table / field definitions, including field names).

`information_schema.columns` is MySQL-specific (I think... It's been a while) so if you're not using MySQL that's probably not going to work. Of course, if you are, the attacker has probably managed to get a list of all field names for all tables making other attacks easier to target and more likely to succeed

Comment: With the trace can it be concluded that the attack is successful or it's a failure? I mean how can I reach a conclusion? Also what happens in frame 75? Thanks.

Comment: All you've shown is a packet capture. In short, the query was sent to the SQL server. Whether the field/table names are correct and whether the data was leaked is impossible to tell from the information given. Assuming the correct names are being used, it's likely the data was leaked. Do you have a capture of the response data too? You could analyse the packet contents to see what results were returned...

Comment: That image link seems to be broken, so can't comment, sorry. That said, unless you've got specific protections in place against SQL injection, I'd say it's likely. Impossible to know for sure with the info you've provided (eg is this a capture between the client and webserver, or webserver and SQL database?). In any case, if I were you, I'd assume compromise and act accordingly.